# Emacs freezes when using split-string in recursive function

Tags: debugging, string, list

I'm trying to figure out why my emacs keeps freezing when running this set of functions to split a string into a list of pairs. Is there some significant overhead happening when using `string-split`? Is there a different way to approach this problem?

```
(setq input "399822 801471
854475 776464
118051 369789
68399 518004
575096 332007
138222 180701
763798 380259
716159 578228
582494 519472
789135 852518
638621 681440")

(defun list-pairs (list)
  (when list
    (cons (split-string (car list) " " t) (list-pairs (cdr list)))))

(list-pairs (split-string input "\n" t))
```

I run this function and my emacs just freezes. I realize the same thing can be accomplished by using `mapcar`

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (split-string x " " t)) (split-string input "\n" t))

(("399822" "801471") ("854475" "776464") 
 ("118051" "369789") ("68399" "518004") 
 ("575096" "332007") ("138222" "180701") 
 ("763798" "380259") ("716159" "578228") 
 ("582494" "519472") ("789135" "852518") 
 ("638621" "681440"))
```

Comment: Your first example with function `list-pairs` runs as expected for me in Emacs 26.3. No freezing. [AFAIK Emacs does not have tail recursion optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38493904/2708138). So your second version is probably better. Note, that the linked SE-entry is quite old. I do not know the current status. They implemented lexical scoping meanwhile. So maybe, there is improvement.

Comment: I think [this comment of Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493904/why-is-there-no-tail-recursion-optimization-in-emacs-lisp-not-but-like-other-sc#comment96860446_38509006) is most interesting in the aspect whether tail recursion will be implemented in the future.

Comment: Noteworthy is that a degree of TCO has been implemented for the [gccemacs](https://akrl.sdf.org/gccemacs.html#orge33b203) project.

Comment: dylanjm, try your code under `emacs -Q`